# Why is my python discord bot not recognising my commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I tried making a discord bot using a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRHUW_KnHLs) however my discord music bot is not recignising any of my commands. It launches with no errors but it doesn't do anything it's supposed to be doing. I am a beginner in python and not sure what I should be doing at this point. Anyone encountered this error before or knows how to fix it?

This is a github page for the code used (mine is a slightly modified version of this to fix some errors) https://github.com/pawel02/music_bot

Every time I try running main.py I get these messages:

```
2023-02-28 21:42:18 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
INFO:discord.client:logging in using static token
2023-02-28 21:42:19 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: d298326aef585afdd846f9f5c4283c69).
INFO:discord.gateway:Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: d298326aef585afdd846f9f5c4283c69)
```

indicating the bot should be running normally, however when I enter a command like '/play [yt link]' it gives me the following error:

```
2023-02-28 21:42:28 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
ERROR:discord.ext.commands.bot:Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
```

Here is my code for main.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
#import all of the cogs

from help_cog import help_cog
from music_cog import music_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

#remove the default help command so that we can write out own
bot.remove_command('help')

#register the class with the bot
async def setup(bot):   
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

#start the bot with our token
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

and here is the code for the music operations (music_cog.py)

```py
from ast import alias
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
        #all the music related stuff
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        # 2d array containing [song, channel]
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

     #searching the item on youtube
    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try: 
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception: 
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            #get the first url
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            #remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # infinite loop checking 
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
            
            #try to connect to voice channel if you are not already connected
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                #in case we fail to connect
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            
            #remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            #you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name = "resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            #try to play next in the queue if it exists
            await self.play_music(ctx)


    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            # display a max of 5 songs in the current queue
            if (i > 4): break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in queue")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
    async def dc(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

finally, here is the code for the help command (help_cog.py)

````py
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    class help_cog(commands.Cog):
        def __init__(self, bot):
            self.bot = bot
            self.help_message = """
    ```
    General commands:
    /help - display all commands
    /p <keywords> - finds and plays song on youtube
    /q - see current music queue
    /skip - skips the current song
    /clear - clears the queue
    /leave - make bot leave vc
    /pause - pauses the current song or resumes if paused 
    /resume - resumes playing the current song
    ```
    """
            self.text_channel_list = []

        #some debug info so that we know the bot has started    
        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                for channel in guild.text_channels:
                    self.text_channel_list.append(channel)

            await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)        

        @commands.command(name="help", help="Displays all the available commands")
        async def help(self, ctx):
            await ctx.send(self.help_message)

        async def send_to_all(self, msg):
            for text_channel in self.text_channel_list:
                await text_channel.send(msg)
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your setup function to add the cog.
Also, Consider putting the setup function inside each cog's file (Outside the class). And use `load_extension` to load them when starting the bot. This is a better way since you can unload/reload it anytime.More [info](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)